# Reading INI File in JAVA

Tags: java

I was trying to get values from an INI File and I'm writing the code in Java.
So far, I have read about this function and yes, it is returning values from the INI File.

```
String property = properties.getProperty("property.name");
```

But [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the code that I need.

Is there a function in Java that is equivalent to the GetPrivateProfileString of C?

Comment: how do you read INI file, and what is the file data look like ?

Comment: Probably the eaisest way is to use something like [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no built-in initialization .INI file support in Java.

Java uses Properties files, which lays its data out like so:

```
propertyOne = 1
propertyTwo = 2
```

C uses Initialization files (.INI), which lays its data out in sections:

```
[Section]
propertyOne = 1
propertyTwo = 2
```

In Java, Properties don't have "sections", but can be divided up into sections by the same convention for naming packages:

```
section.propertyOne = 1
section.propertyTwo = 2
```

So you would call `properties.getProperty("section.propertyOne");`, where in INI you call the section first and then the property instead of as one.

INI files offer some more usefulness, but are not natively supported. A good 3rd party Java API for dealing with INI files is ini4j.

http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

The reason for this is that .INI is a Windows-specific file. You won't really find .INI files on other operating systems, and Java is a cross-platform language.

Comment: ohh , ok.
that's bad then. Thank you for your explanation and pointing me to ini4j. I will try to follow that then.

Comment: No problem, though I wouldn't say it's bad. If you need to read an INI file created by someone else, or generate one for another program, use ini4j. If you're creating your own INI file that contains stuff related to your Java program, you should use Properties. That way, you don't have to add INI support. I updated my code with an example on sections with Properties

Comment: i have tried putting this "properties.getProperty("SECTION_ID.UserID");" in my code but the return value is null. >.<

Comment: What does your properties file look like? It should have a line that contains and looks like "SECTION_ID.UserID = 42"

Comment: I just copied this from a tutorial that I found. 
Properties properties = new Properties();

Comment: When you create a new Properties object, it has no data in it. Either load an external file via properties.load(), or use properites.putProperty() to first set the property. You have to give it something first before you can read from it

Comment: `You won't really find .INI files on other operating systems` which is not correct. You won't find files with extension .ini as this is Windows invention, but the format is standardized and used across all major systems. For example check samba configuration format, or any another linux system config files.